# How to change regular data into url query parameters in php

Tags: php, redirect

I want to create a redirect in PHP where I want to pass `+` sign as `%2B` in URL but whenever, I'm using `header("Location: url ")` . It is passing the `+` sign as `+`, So at the end server, after decoding it is showing a blank space instead of showing `+` sign.

```
<?php

    echo $eqn=$_GET['eqn'];
    $ord=$_GET['ord'];

    

    header("Location: http://example.com/$eqn")
?>
```

Basically, I've created a HTML form where I am passing data to the following php page, Here I want to redirect to a url like `http://example.com?i0=encoded-value-required/aa`.
And here in the `encoded-value-required` parameter, I want to pass the `+` sign as `%2B` in the header location.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

Like ADyson wrote you should use `urlencode`.

```php
$eqn = urlencode($_GET['eqn']);
```

Comment: Is this advice duplicated ANYWHERE on Stack Overflow before today? If so, please close as a duplicate instead of answering.